# Uninstall Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell-platform

I mispelled the Prefix, after creating the directory under /usr/local as haskell-platform (suggested by the instructions), as /usr/loca when I ran configure, but didn't notice until later.  Rather than leave a munged directory out there, I moved it to its proper location.  Of course, it all broke.  Turns out that /usr/loca is embedded all over the place.

I then Synaptic removed ghc6 (this is ubuntu 10.04, and the instructions day to run 6.12.1/2010.1).  When I reinstalled, it still thinks that the packages are on /usr/loca ???  I even removed package.cache, but it was recreated with /usr/loca in the file paths, even when I run configure with the correct path on /usr/local.

Where is this prefix coming from?  At this point, I'd just as soon get rid of the whole thing.  Where do I look for the bits and pieces to delete?  None of the wiki's or docs discuss how to get rid of this thing.  There seems to be an Uninstaller in the Mac distro, but none that I can find for *nix.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the answer, I'm pretty sure, is that embedded paths were in the cabal config file in the `~/.cabal` directory.